# Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common gives "Access Is Denied" error

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

Using .NET 4.0, I have a small ASP.NET app that utilized the ReportViewer object, I have created a web page that takes some user input and generates a report that is displayed using the ReportViewer control with ProcessingMode set to local.

Naturally, it works perfectly when run via VS 2010 in debugging mode and if I publish it to IIS running on my local machine.  However, when I push it to production, I get the following error when actually trying to run the report[image]

For the image impaired:

```
Failed to load expression host assembly. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.
```

I have verified that the assembly (as well as the other reportviewer dependencies) is in the GAC.  There don't seem to be any errors in the event log on the server.

Any ideas what the permission problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, the production environment I was deploying to is a web farm and the virtual directories point to a location on a network drive.  When I tried deploying to a non farm server, with a virtual directory located on the server itself, this worked.  The permissions are identical in the two environments, so I can only assume that something about this control didn't like being located on a different box than IIS and ASP.NET.

I'm not sure if this is actually an "answer", so apologies in advance if I've handled this wrong from a stackover perspective.

Comment: is it bad form to check this as answered or should I leave it unanswered?

Comment: Maybe edit the original question, and include the answer underneath (will help future googlers).

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as the solution.  As far as i know it's not bad form since you don't actually gain reputation from it.  In fact, I think it's better to actually check it as the solution since future readers can see at a glance that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

What authentication are you using in IIS? (e.g. windows, anonymous, ASP.NET impersonation)

Comment: I've tried using windows and forms authentication (the above example uses forms).  I get the following error when using windows authentication:  iled to load expression host assembly. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The account used is a computer account. Use your global user account or local user account to access this server. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070710)